# Create Samsung Smart TV Offline Application

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I've been asked to create a Samsung Smart TV offline App but I really don't know what it means to Offline Application.

The client said me

> The app has no GUI. It's not like a regular app. The TV will be
>   pointed to a URL. That URL has specific Samsung TV instructions to
>   download the files and when the TV has it, it will open the zip and
>   display the content as required.

I've setup the development environment and have studied about **Samsung AppsFramework** and learned how to start an application but really confusing about the offline Application.

Could anybody please make me understand that what the client does exactly want?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What the client wants in my opinion is an app that can work on the smart TV without having to connect to the internet.

It would obviously need to connect to obtain the download files, but once the app is installed it will have offline functionality and not need to connect to the internet to run.

Have a look at http://electron.atom.io/ to build cross platform applications like this.

It is really difficult to say what they mean by offline as we dont have a brief. But offline generally refers to an app that has everything in the initial download. Example, a dictionary app will have all of the words and definitions in the download so they are always available even if the device is not connected.

Hope this helps

Comment: But how to decide when the app will download contents from internet?

Comment: That is up to you, download with updates, download when connected and cache, depends on project

Answer (score 0):

Samsung API provides interface for reading and writing files so you can download and store something for later offline use.

Alternatively you can use `localStorage` API.

> The app has no GUI

This part is strange. Launched app occupy whole screen. You need some use-case description from client. Find out what problem is your client want to solve with this app.

Comment: Actually the client wants to show some image slideshows on a LFD tv

Comment: I'll be having some images regarding each device ID and then show them as slideshow for advertisement purpose.

Comment: Slideshow expected work without internet access? and slides should be downloaded separately?